# Set checkbox error message in a Symfony form type

Tags: symfony

I would like to change the error message if the therm and conditions are not accepted. With the code below if gives the standard error message. I have added the translation domain and invalid message name but this has no effect. What is wrong in this?

```
->add('terms', 'checkbox', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'constraints' => array(new Assert\IsTrue()),
                'translation_domain' => 'validators',
                'invalid_message' => 'accept_conditions',
            ))
```

Comment: This code is default?

Comment: No it is my own code. It does only not show the message that is in my translation file.

Comment: Change invalid_message by `invalid' if you check the documentation in validators its can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
'constraints' => array(new Assert\IsTrue()),
```

by:

```
'required' => true,
```

Constraints have their own translation messages, which is why your translation did not have any effect. If you really want/need to keep using `Assert\IsTrue`, specify a custom message **inside the constraint:**

```
'constraints' => array(
    new Assert\IsTrue(
        array('message' => 'accept_conditions')
    )
),
```